# iPad Media query

Tags: css, ipad, tablet

I've tried a few suggestions 
(device-width:768px)
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)

but I can't seem to get anything to work to make CSS target iPad. I'm only testing on an iPad 1st gen though. Is there a separate Media Query for 1st gen?

Also, I'm not sure if it's important to mention that I used:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May have gone overboard, but until it becomes a problem I'm not going to adjust it.
I used:

```
@media(min-device-width: 650px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to use the aspect ratios vs the widths:

**iPhone < 5:**

```
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {}
```

**iPhone 5:**

```
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {}
```

**iPad:**

```
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 3/4) {}
```

Comment: does my update make a difference? The aspect ratio didn't work